# Is it possible to have a plot with ticks but without their numbers?

Tags: pgfplots, ticks

I want to save space when stacking many axes over each other. The plots have common domain, and I don't want to lose space for the same information repeated (the numbers on the x-axis). Is it possible to disable the x-numbering of ticks ? I found till now the opotion `\empty` but that removes the ticks so no grids for them can be ploted. I want to keep the grid.

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
  \pgfplotsset{width={\textwidth},height={6 cm},
  xmin=0,xmax=7}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ylabel={$y$},
    grid=major,
%xtick=\empty,
    ]
    \addplot[blue, domain=2:4] {1};
    \addplot[red, dashed, domain=2-2:4-2] {2*x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}\vspace{.5 cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ylabel={$y$},
    grid=major,
    ]
    \addplot[blue, domain=2:4] {1};
    \addplot[red, dashed, domain=2-1:4-1] {2*x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}\vspace{.5 cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xlabel= {$x$}, ylabel={$y$},
    grid=major,
    ]
    \addplot[blue, domain=2:4] {1};
    \addplot[red, dashed, domain=2:4] {2*x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\label{fig:sin}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `xticklabels={}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{width={\textwidth},height={6 cm},
  xmin=0,xmax=7}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ylabel={$y$},
    grid=major,
    xticklabels={},
    ]
    \addplot[blue, domain=2:4] {1};
    \addplot[red, dashed, domain=2-2:4-2] {2*x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```